# Adding new partitions to existing table - Oracle 9i

Tags: database, partitioning, oracle9i

Afternoon all,

Quick question I hope. I am about to put additional partitions into an Oracle 9i database table as the max partition is getting large. Other systems update/insert into this table regularly. My question to you is, do I need to take the database offline in order to run these new partitions in or should I be able to do this without revoking access.

Example of the script I'm using is:
ALTER TABLE TEST_TABLE SPLIT PARTITION WOMAX AT ('038') INTO (PARTITION WO037,PARTITION WOMAX);

Thanks,
Louise

Answer (score 0):

It was decided that because other systems were inserting and updating the tables, that we would suspend these services to reduce any risk.